# Changing VS 2012 Ultimate to VS 2012 Professional, is there any impact on SharePoint?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In SharePoint 2013 Uninstalling VS 2012 Ultimate & installing VS 2012 Professional on SharePoint 2013 server, will it impact existing applications development on SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. there won't be any impact on your SP infrastructure. VS 2012 ULTIMATE/PROFESSIONAL is just a tool/IDE to enable a smooth SharePoint development experience.

Using VS Versions, you would be developing SP solutions as packages [.wsp files], and using PowerShell or stsadm command line tools you would deploy on the SharePoint farm.Without VS, you wont be able to develop *.wsp packages.

There are some differences between the two,Ultimate / Professional.If you use ULTIMATE, you can have unit testing framework attached to it.

Ultimate version has all the features available in Professional version + some additional features.

[Difference-between-VS-ULTIMATE-PROFESSIONAL](http://karthikdodda.blogspot.in/2012/12/differences-between-vs2012-professional.html)

[Compare-Ultimate-Professional](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/news/visual-studio-2012-editions-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Fakes doesn't work on VS Professional. 
Consider that if you are doing Unit Testing and using SPEmulators you will need to use VS Ultimate/Premium.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will not see any difference.

But if you need to update your solutions, or add something new... you will see that some advanced features (Like test automation stuff, as said by klewgenius) will be missing.

ANyway, for basic sharepoint development, considering webparts, event receivers, even workflows... you will see no changes. Specially considering that most of sharepoint development is built with Office Developer Tools (VS add-in).